# Convert CKEDITOR to TextArea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have a text area and a button. On click of that button I'm converting textarea to ckeditor.
My additional requirement is that , on click of other button the ckeditor must be converted back to textarea.
My code:

```
<textarea name="editor"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="CreateEditor('editor')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CreateEditor(name) {

        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
        if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }

        CKEDITOR.replace(name, {
            toolbarStartupExpanded: false,
            autoGrow_onStartup: true
        });

        if (CKEDITOR.env.webkit) {
            CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function (e) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset")[0].contentDocument.body.parentNode.contentEditable = "true";
                if (typeof FocusedElement !== 'undefined') {
                    FocusedElement = e.editor.name;
                }
            });
        }
    }

</script>
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have that in your own code:

```
    function DestroyEditor(name) {

      var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
      if (editor) { editor.destroy(true); }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code should give you the plane text from the CKEditor

```
var text = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.document.getBody().getText();
```

Now, you have to remove CKEDitor for that here is the line of code

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor.element.remove()
```

Now, you can add the `<textarea name="editor"></textarea>` to your dom again assign text to it like

```
$("textarea[name=editor]").value = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a more common use case - the requirement to get the HTML code back from CKEditor (not the text), use [editor.getData()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-getData). See the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_savedata) for more details.